# What does it mean to have an input separated by \r?

Tags: arrays, input, carriage-return

What does it mean to have an input separated by a `\r` (carriage return) when we ask the user to input some values ? Does using a carriage return means to input is something like this :

```
  > 1 
  > 2
  > 3
```

I need to save these values but I am not sure how to implement the carriage return between each input? also does using a carriage return determines the end an input?

Comment: "does using a carriage return determines the end an input" that depends entirely on where the data is coming from.

Comment: @joe from user input

Comment: What language? What OS?

Comment: @joe does it really matter? I need to implement this in a couple of different languages

Comment: Yes, unfortunately (for reasons detailed in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Carriage return means 'go to the start of the line'. Line feed means 'go down by one row'. They are hang-overs from teletype machines.

Some operating systems use `\r` (return) for a 'new line', some use `\r\n` (return, new line), some (used to use) `\n` (new line). Your programming language probably has a "split lines" function which works on a broad range of input.

The danger you can run into is that if you have the string `one\ntwo\r\nthree\nfour` (which is perfectly possible), you can split it by

- by `\n` to get `["one", "two\r", "three", "four"]`
- by `\r` to get `["one\ntwo", "\nthree\nfour"]`
- by `\r\n` to get `["one\ntwo", "three\nfour"]`.
- by `(\r\n|\r|\n)` to get `["one", "two", "three", "four"]` (the last is a regular expression). I'm sure there are better regular expressions.

You should probably read [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) to get a full picture. This [article by Jeff Atwood](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-great-newline-schism/) is also good.

Comment: so the input should be in this sequence `>1\r\2\r\3\r4\r` and not `>1 [enter] > 2 [enter]` ?

Comment: Input from where? Collected how? Try and imagine I know nothing about you, your problem or your computer.

Comment: input from the user in the terminal using linux OS. For example in the terminal I ask use to input values and the user must input each value separated by a carriage return

Comment: So on linux it's probably `\r\n`. Depending on how (you still didn't say how - what language and what function?) the input function may have stopped collecting input when the user presses return (so it might strip newline characters), or when they hit `^D`.